# How to hexagonate an image

Tags: image

I am making a biome map based off the entities in that area but I'd like to make it hexagonal shape instead of a cube. How would I do this? Or at least a better defining word on what I'm speaking of so I can google it.

EDIT: By hexagonate I mean turn an image that is normally rendered as this:
[image]

And here is somewhat what I want it to look like but instead of the noise the biomes.
[image]

Comment: Could you edit this question to add details and maybe a drawing/image to show what you are trying to say. 

Also, this is the go-to hexagon math reference : http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/